# Энергетические напитки

Tags: выбор-слов

Возможны ли сочетания "энергетический чай, кофе" в значении "наполняющие энергией"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такие сочетания возможны только при описании рыночного продукта, которому производитель намеренно придал *дополнительные* качества (например, путём создания повышенной концентрации тонизирующего компонента чая или кофе или введения добавок). Прилагательное здесь описывает **предназначение** напитка (пробудить энергетические ресурсы организма), а не известные тонизирующие *свойства*, изначально присущие таким известным напиткам как чай или кофе.